# Where was Stan Lee's cameo in Deadpool 2?

Tags: marvel, x-men-cinematic-universe, deadpool, deadpool-2

There are two places where it could have been but it was so quick I didn't really see it.

- When going through the X-men mansion some older faces can be seen hiding from Wade before they shut the door. He could have been amongst the crowd.
- I have a feeling I saw his face painted on the side of a building but it was artsy and only shown for a moment so again I'm not sure if it was him or not.

**Where was Stan Lee's cameo?**

---

On a side note I know about the cameo from the [teaser trailer](https://youtu.be/2YpnOHCoY3k?t=2m5s) but I thought there was one in the film too.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

According to Rhett Reese and Paul Wernick, the writers for Deadpool 2, there was a bust in the X-Mansion of Stan Lee that get's knocked over. They also mention the cameo he did in the trailer. As well as those two Reese alludes to his face being in there somewhere which is no doubt a reference to the painting on the side of the building.

> **There's no Stan Lee cameo this time around. Did you consider one?**
>
> **Wernick:** I think there's a painting of Stan in the [X-]Mansion, is there not Rhett?
>
> **Reese:** I think there was a bust of a statue that gets knocked over, was that his head?
>
> **Wernick:** It was...
>
> **Reese:** I don't know if you can make it out ... He had just had cameo'd for is in the short that we did where Deadpool is in a telephone booth … So Stan did cameo for us in that. I'm not sure why it didn't work out this time. But we did try to at least make a nod to him. I know his face is in there somewhere.
>
> <sup>[The Hollywood Reporter, How 'Deadpool 2' Writers Snuck Heart Into the Raunchy Franchise](https://www.hollywoodreporter.com/heat-vision/deadpool-2-writers-tease-deadpool-3-future-franchise-1112938)</sup>

I have yet to watch the film back but according to [this reddit post](https://www.reddit.com/r/Marvel/comments/99zuxr/the_other_stan_lee_cameo_in_deadpool_2/) this is the bust/statue:

[image: Stan Lee bust]

Of course as I mention in my question and is answered by [@Doctor 333](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/187805/58193) we also see a portrait of Stan Lee's face on the side of a building as Domino is parachuting down to the convoy.

> According to social buzz, there is another super-short cameo of Lee in Deadpool 2 that fans should be able to spot. In the latter-half of the film, the mouthy Marvel legend leads his X-Force team into a plane jump. When Domino is seen landing, she touches down outside a mural which features a giant image of Lee’s face. So, fans will want to keep an eye out for that.
>
> <sup>[Comicbook, ‘Deadpool 2’ Writers Reveal Stan Lee’s Cameo](http://comicbook.com/marvel/2018/05/18/-deadpool-2-writers-reveal-stan-lee-s-cameo/)</sup>

[image: Stan Lee side of wall painting]

Comment: For the record, the bust that falls over is facing *away* from the camera.

Comment: @Valorum I didn't actually see the bust when I watched it (or didn't notice if it was facing away) and haven't re-watched yet to look out for it.

Answer (score 5):

He had a portrait on the side of a building when the prison truck was driving into the city.

Comment: Hello and welcome to SFF! While this may answer the question (and is what I remember) it would be better to try and include some sort of evidence into your answer (hard at the moment I know). Also don't forget to register your account and take the [tour]!

Comment: Are you certain this is the _only_ cameo that Stan Lee had, there was no other scenes with him?